# Does $x^n\otimes a=(x\otimes a)^n $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $f:A\to B $ be integral homomorphism. For $x\in B, a\in A $, in $B\otimes_A A $

Does  $x^n\otimes a=(x\otimes a)^n $?

Comment: As someone just beginning to get comfortable with tensors and whatnot, the downvoter would do me a great favor by explaining why.

Comment: I think because the title was WHY,, then I changed it to DOES. I just assumed that why I got downvote.

Comment: Well, if my opinion counts, that's a blindingly idiotic reason to downvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in general! By definition of multiplication in the tensor product, $$(x\otimes a)^n = x^n\otimes a^n.$$

You should be aware that $B\otimes_A A\cong B$ by the map induced by $b\otimes a \mapsto b\cdot f(a)$. So we have $(x\otimes a)^n = x^n\otimes a^n = x^n \otimes a$ if and only if $x^n\cdot f(a)^n = x^n\cdot f(a)$ if and only if $x^n\cdot f(a)\cdot (f(a)^{n-1} - 1) = 0$ in $B$. If $B$ happens to be an integral domain, this is true if and only if $x = 0$ or $f(a) = 0$ (in either case, both tensors are $0$) or if $f(a)$ is an $(n-1)$-root of unity in $B$.

Comment: I think I see now, I was originally trying to show $B\otimes_A A_p $ is integral over $A_p $. SINCE $B $ is integral over $A $, I can use the equation $\sum a_i b^i $ to get $\sum a_i (b^i\otimes a) $ for it to be integral. Thanks